# How to make one command out of two

Tags: powershell

I'm searching a directory for files that have pieces of a name in the files. How can I make one command out of the two I have?

```
get-childitem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_test_me.", ".") }
get-childitem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".test.") }
```

Running the commands work but I would like to clean it up a little with only needing one command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could chain the Replace-Calls

```
get-childitem "\\myfileserver\out\*" | foreach { rename-item $_ $_.Name.Replace("_test_me.", ".").Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".test.") }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. "*" is not necessary into your get-childitem command path
2. you can specify  -file argument for take only file (better performance)
3. you can specify a clause where for rename only file with your patterns (better performance and why rename allwhen we can rename only necessary)
4. not necessary to use foreach, pipe work with rename-item command

like this:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\myfileserver\out" -file | 
        where {$_.Name -like "*_test_me.*" -or $_.Name -like "*.vfmpclmadj.*"} | 
                rename-item -NewName {$_.Name.Replace("_test_me.", ".").Replace(".vfmpclmadj.", ".test.")}
```